# When and how do PS+ free games expire?

Tags: ps4

If I download ps plus free games to external storage and don’t go online when playing them, how do they stop access to them when the membership expires

Answer (score 2):

> As soon as you download the game, it'll look into your ps plus subscription end date and put the expiry date on the game. You can check by hitting Options and the Information.

Looks like checks are periodical:

> Your PS Plus status will need to be checked when a game is first played. After that, there will be a periodic check, which I beleive is in the region of each 30 days.

I didn't find any official sources, but [multiple](https://community.playstation.com/content/pdc/us/en_US/pdc-communities/support/Consoles-Peripherals.topic.html/can_t_play_downloade-ytdK.html) [threads](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/6zg0jn/can_you_play_free_ps_plus_games_without_a/) [confirm](https://www.bungie.net/en/Forums/Post/243602254).

Comment: Thanks.. I think it’s a bit of a rip off but, what can the minions do eh? 

Comment: Its not clear in this answer that they need authenticating again before the subscription expiry date.If you have the console offline for a period of time those games will show as locked until the PlayStation can re authenticate with PSN. It has happened to me on a few occasions. From my experience they need to be able to phone home every so often to reset the clock. This is based on my experience with the PS4 and Vita. I have also had the ps plus games lock when PSN is having issues.